# Robot Framework String Formatting

Tags: automation, automated-tests, robotframework

How can I make a string format like following:

```
${original} = MZ**77050000*******228  
${desired} =  MZXX 7705 0000 XXXX XXXX 28
```

I managed to replace the * to X, and add the spaces as following, but yet can't format the 3rd last int to X:

```
${rep_temp} =  Replace String  ${original}    *   X

FOR  ${i}  IN  4  8  12  16  20  22
            ${y} =   Evaluate    ${i} - 4
            ${temp} =       Get Substring     ${rep_temp}    ${y}    ${i}
            ${new_temp} =  Set Variable      ${new_temp} ${temp}
            ${new_temp} =  Strip String      ${new_temp}
            log to console     new_temp-->${new_temp}
        END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [Replace String Using Regexp](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Replace%20String%20Using%20Regexp) keyword from the String library. I do not know the exact criteria of the original string, but let's say there are `*******` so 7 `*` followed by 3 digits and you want to convert the 1st digit of the 3 to `*`, then to `X`.

You can do that like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     String

*** Variables ***
${original}    MZ**77050000*******228 

*** Test Cases ***
Test Replace
    ${desired}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${original}    \\*\{7\}\\d     ********
    ${desired}=    Replace String Using Regexp    ${desired}     \\*     X
    # add the spaces
```

You have to use double escaping in regexes in a robot file and you have to escape `{` and `}` as well because those are Robot Framework special characters. So this `\\*\{7\}\\d` is equivalent with this `\*{7}\d` and will match for 7 `*` followed by a digit.

This would be the output, you have to add the spaces and it is done.

[image]

Comment: It did the job, thank you (Y), but what if the numbers are changing, what do you suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: here it is: MZ**44268316*******359

Comment: @Zain If you try my code with `MZ**44268316*******359`, it should work.